# Why does GDB start a new shell and how to disable this behaviour?

Tags: c, gdb, symbols

I was figuring out a problem where starting the application from GDB results in a symbol lookup error, but starting it from the shell works.

It turns out that whenever you start a program from within GDB it will start a new shell and thus override all environment variables I had set before starting GDB (like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

This is not really the behavior I want. Can someone explain the rationale behind this, or tell me how I can turn this off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing that you *unconditionally* set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `~/.cshrc` or the like. So if from a shell prompt you do this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo  # or for csh:
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH foo
$SHELL -c 'echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

the result is something other than `foo`. Don't do *that*.

Usually this happens to CSH users, who neglected to protect their `~/.cshrc` against non-interactive shells. It could also happen to BASH users who set their `BASH_ENV`.

Comment: I just ran into this exact mistake in my configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem. I find that in inferior.h (source code of gdb [gdb/inferior.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-250/src/gdb/inferior.h))
there is a macro `STARTUP_WITH_SHELL`, there is also a piece of comment as

```
/* If STARTUP_WITH_SHELL is set, GDB's "run"
   will attempts to start up the debugee under a shell.
   This is in order for argument-expansion to occur. E.g.,
   (gdb) run *
   The "*" gets expanded by the shell into a list of files.
   While this is a nice feature, it turns out to interact badly
   with some of the catch-fork/catch-exec features we have added.
   In particular, if the shell does any fork/exec's before
   the exec of the target program, that can confuse GDB.
   To disable this feature, set STARTUP_WITH_SHELL to 0.
   To enable this feature, set STARTUP_WITH_SHELL to 1.
   The catch-exec traps expected during start-up will
   be 1 if target is not started up with a shell, 2 if it is.
   - RT
   If you disable this, you need to decrement
   START_INFERIOR_TRAPS_EXPECTED in tm.h. */
#define STARTUP_WITH_SHELL 1
#if !defined(START_INFERIOR_TRAPS_EXPECTED)
#define START_INFERIOR_TRAPS_EXPECTED   2
#endif
```

Then I set `STARTUP_WITH_SHELL` as 0 and decremented `START_INFERIOR_TRAPS_EXPECTED`
and recompiled my gdb. After that gdb didn't start from shell any more.

Comment: Current gdb allows you to do it by: `set startup-with-shell off`

Answer (score 2):

When you start gdb from the shell, you start it as a new process, there's no way around that. In Unix new processes inherit some of the environment of the parent.

To make sure a variable is inherited, if you're using a bourne-like shell, try exporting it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...
```

Comment: I am guessingh that the problem is that OP sets his `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.bashrc` or something like that, and that setting *overwrites* whatever he set before invoking GDB,].

Comment: You nailed it, @EmployedRussian !

Answer (score 1):

The debuggee (*inferior* in gdb parlance) is always started with a clean environment in order to get more reproducible results. In order to set a variable there, use the

```
set env VARNAME=VALUE
```

command before running.

Comment: If by "clean environment" you mean something other than a copy of GDB's own environment (plus whatever `set env` commands have been executed), they you are quite mistaken.