# Can bashrc test to see if it is being invoked by GDB?

Tags: xcode, bash, gdb, osx-snow-leopard

My bashrc file (on OS X) sets up a number of functions for every user. Unfortunately, gdb invokes the shell ($SHELL is /bin/bash), and is tripping up on these. Since Xcode is calling gdb, I can't change gdb's command line arguments.

My bashrc tests [-z $PS1 ] and exits if true, but apparently gdb is calling as an interactive shell. I've looked at creating a .gdbinit file, but don't see where that will help.

The last answer at [Why does GDB start a new shell and how to disable this behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877969/why-does-gdb-start-a-new-shell-and-how-to-disable-this-behaviour) suggested recompiling gdb to avoid having it invoke the shell.

I've thought about renaming /usr/bin/gdb and creating a script there that will unset SHELL and then execute the renamed gdb, but for a number of reasons I'm not thrilled about this, so I guess I'm looking at recompiling gdb unless anyone knows another way to tell if gdb is starting bash.

Comment: Dump the environment/etc. in your `.bashrc` file and see if there's anything else you can trigger on in how `gdb` is setting up the environment? Also, what is `gdb` tripping up on exactly? It might be easier to fix/work-around those problems directly.

Comment: See if this quick work-around helps. `PPID=$(ps -oPPID= --pid $$); if [ "$(ps -o comm= --pid $PPID)" == "gdb" ]; then echo do something; fi`

Comment: You could use gdb's [set exec-wrapper](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#set-exec_002dwrapper) command so that gdb will run a shell script when it starts the target running. That script can clean out whatever is necessary in the environment before exec-ing the target.

Comment: I followed anishsane's suggestion-- turned out (and I should have known this) bash already correctly sets $PPID internally. Under OS X, the ps syntax is slightly different, so I ended up with: `if [  "$(ps -o command= -p $PPID)" == "gdb" ]; then echo gdb is calling me; fi`. That's when I found out that the environment present when Xcode is called is being set again under gdb. So I used `env -i open /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app` and it took care of the issue.